# how to store hash value in cookie with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

I want to implement a remember me option for the login

therefore I want to store both username and hashed password to a cookie, and check it when the user come back to the site.

I tried to do

```
cookies[:user] = { :value => {:username => @user.username, :password =>
@user.hashed_password}, :expires => 1.month.from_now }
```

it's save the cookie, but I can't read its attributes

```
cookies[:user].username # doesn't work
```

by the way, is it the best solution to implement RememberMe?

Comment: Why won't you use devise gem?

Comment: I'm building my first app with rails, and I want better understanding of what happens under the hood.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746155/automatic-login-with-rails/1787047#1787047) can help you

Comment: This answers his problem creating a "remember me" function, but it does not answer the question as stated: "how to store hash value in cookie with rails 3".

Answer (score 3):

Better to use the `session` method for setting these sorts of things.  Feel free to keep the session in a cookie by using the default `:cookie_store` setting in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`.

```
session[:user] = { :foo => { :bar => 'woot' } }
```

Then later...

```
session[:user][:foo][:bar] # => 'woot'
```

Comment: how can I change the session expiration? When the session based on cookie I think that the user can just change the user_id and logged in as other user, am I right?

Comment: Yes, if you used something simple like the `user_id` then it will be trivial to hack.  That's why few people use the `:cookie_store`

Answer (score 3):

From what I have [read](http://www.quarkruby.com/2007/10/21/sessions-and-cookies-in-ruby-on-rails#scinrails), one can only store strings in cookies. In order to store other data structures one need to serialize the data, such as JSON or YAML.

And I guess Session object has this built-in

Comment: Using new-style hash syntax for brevity: `cookies[:user] = { value: { username: @user.username, password: @user.hashed_password }.to_json, expires: 1.month.from_now }` then later use: `foo = JSON.parse(cookies[:user])`. foo will now be a Hash, but with keys all converted to strings, so you may want to use: `foo = JSON.parse(cookies[:user]).with_indifferent_access`. Then foo[:username] won't be nil.

Comment: @MikeJ Your comment should be an answer (and accepted), as it is concise and has a concrete example.